# Moving AD Users based on -Office to OU

Tags: powershell, directory, exchange-server, azure-powershell

I am working on a Powershell script to move users to the correct OU based on the number in the $_.grade field of my CSV.

Of course, we have users with 1-12 for their grade in the Office field. In AD, we only have Primary, Middle, and High for our OUs under Students.

My goal is to mass import students (which I have achieved and it works perfectly.) but then to also move them based on their grade.

Primary OU is grades 00-04
Middle OU is grades 05-08
High OU is grades 09-12

```
$Import.Add_Click( {
    Import-CSV -Path $filename | ForEach {
        Set-ADUser -Identity $_.user -Description $_.desc -Office $_.grade -replace @{UserType="Student"}
    
        $Information.text = "Description and UserType have been set."

        Import-CSV -Path $filename | ForEach {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "O365-StudentLicense" -Members $_.user}
        $Information.text = "All imported accounts now have a mailbox."
    }
})
```

This is my current code that works. No attempt for actually making it do what I want, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `-like` wildcard string comparison operator:

```
Import-CSV -Path $filename | ForEach {
    $OU = if($_.grade -like '0[0-4]'){
        'Primary'
    }
    elseif($_.grade -like '0[5-8]'){
        'Middle'
    }
    elseif($_.grade -like '09' -or $_.grade -like '1[0-2]'){
        'High'
    }

    $OUPath = "OU=${OU} School,OU=Parent,DC=domain,DC=tld"

    Move-ADObject -Identity $_.user -TargetPath $OUPath
}
```

`[0-4]` means "any of the characters in this range", so `0[0-4]` will match a `0` followed by any one of `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.